# position changed when calling notifydatasetchanged in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView to display the list of rows, each row include download button. when download of particular row's item completes, notifydatasetchanged will call and download button of downloaded row has to change to "read". but in my case other rows button changing instead of downloaded row.Please anybody suggest me how to resolve this issue.

```
// adapter
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private Cursor mDataset;


        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // each data item is just a string in this case


            public Button download_btn;

            public MyViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);

                download_btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.download_btn);

            }
        }


        void setDataSet(Cursor mDataset) {
            this.mDataset = mDataset;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public MyAdapter(Cursor myDataset) {

            this.mDataset = myDataset;

        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,

                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);

            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;

            this.mDataset.moveToPosition(position);

            switch (this.mDataset.getInt(this.mDataset.getColumnIndex("IS_DOWNLOADED"))) {

                case 0:
                   // when download not completed. 
                     myViewHolder.download_btn.setText("Download");
                     break;


                case 1:
                  // when download  completed.  
                    myViewHolder.download_btn.setText("Read");
                    break;
            }
        }        
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

          return this.mDataset.getCount();

        }

    }




// notifydatasetchanged called when download completes

  myAdapter.setDataSet(cursor);
```

when calling notifydatasetchanged it was using old cursor values instead of new cursor.

Comment: What you need to do? You want to hide the button for each row in this list when the data is downloaded? Have you a way that identify the object you are downloading? Can you post your `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: i have edited my question. when notifydatasetchanged call button of particular view has to change to "read". but in my case other view button is changing instead of downloaded content.

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary double newlines in your code.

Comment: Your adapter code is correct,I guess there are some problems elsewhere and you should post other related code.PS:you'd better use `notifyItemChanged()` for better performance.

Comment: When i call notifydatasetchanged it will come to case 1 (downloaded position) but   myViewHolder.download_btn not setting to read.i mean views are not updating.. i tried notifyItemChanged() also.

Comment: if i once change activity it will change.